# Как правильно загружать файл через InputFile? Blazor Server

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

Я пытаюсь вот так записать файл `<InputFile class="form-control" id="photo" @bind-Value="@Actor.Photo" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif" />`  У Photo тип данных byte[], но почему-то файл не записывается в переменную.

Answer (score 0):

```
<InputFile class="form-control" id="photo" OnChange="@SingleUpload" @bind-Value="@Actor.Photo" accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.png,.gif" />

private async Task SingleUpload(InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        await e.File.OpenReadStream().CopyToAsync(ms);
        var bytes = ms.ToArray();
        Actor.Photo = bytes;
    }
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]